# In below rust code if condition hits twice

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, rust

While debugging below rust code in VSCode, the line with if condition is visited second time, after executing printlin! macro, inside if condition. Thus it looks like if condition is evaluated twice. Is this expected?. I am using F10 key during debugging. I am just getting started with rustlang and VSCode on Ubuntu.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");
    println!("Please input your guess");

    let mut str_buffer = String::new(); 

    let str_length_from_read_line = io::stdin().read_line(&mut str_buffer)
                                               .expect("Failed to read line");
    
    let input_str_len = str_buffer.len();
    
    if input_str_len == str_length_from_read_line {
      println!("Input string length is same as value of size returned by read_line.");
    }
    
   println!("You guess is : {}", str_buffer);
}
```

Comment: I found the debugging experience with VSCode for Rust fairly underwhelming, irrespective of the debugger used. Seeing the next statement marker jump back to a previous location is common, though I'm not sure what gets the debugger(s) so confused. I've since switched to using Visual Studio proper for debugging. Even without *any* language support the debugging experience is still lightyears ahead of what VSCode currently has to offer. Which is odd, as both debuggers use the same data.

Comment: trust the code more than your "debug tool"

Comment: VSCode for Rust do not show all methods via intellisense after typing dot. The gap between user experience with native GUI vs web technology is still big enough.  The trend of making everything with web technology is quite strong but pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is not intuitive but it is, in my opinion correct.  VSCode is not getting confused about the line with `if ... {` or indicating that the `if` conditional is being executing a second time it's returning to the `if ...` line because that line has not finished being evaluated.

Here's why: in Rust `if` blocks are expressions, so they must always resolve to a value (and type).  In your example, the `if` expression evaluates to the unit type (`()`).  In your code, the debugger returns to the `if ...` line because after the `println!` has executed the `if` expression has evaluated to `()` and the debugger returns to the beginning of the `if` expression because now something needs to be done with the value `()`.  In your code it is simply discarded.

This is more clearly seen when the result of an `if` expression is being bound to a variable. Take the following example:

```
let a = 4;
let b = 5;
let x = if a < b {
    1
} else {
    2
};
```

If you step through this code with a debugger.  when you are on line 3 and hit `F10` the if condition will evaluate to true and the debugger will step to line 4.  Hit `F10` again and the debugger will complete the if expression, which evaluates to `1`.  The debugger will return to line 3 because the if expression has finished being evaluated but you still have to complete the binding of the result (`1`) to the variable `x`.  Hit `F10` again and the result (`1`) will be bound to `x` and the debugger will move to the line of code following `let x = if ...`.

Comment: I just checked, and for me the behavior has changed: Single-stepping hits lines 1, 2, 4, 8, ... Seems like someone finally got rid of the non-intuitive behavior (that never seems to have worked anyway), and went with what people expect. The fact that the value of an expression gets bound to a variable doesn't warrant stepping back to that location. Simply updating the local watch window is sufficient. The operation is called *"Step Over"* after all, not *"Step Into"*.

Comment: Though, if you replace `a < b` with `std::env::args().count() > 42`, the debugger jumps back from line 6 (or 4) to 3. I guess that just proves my point: It never seems to work.

Comment: @IInspectable: I'd say that in this latter case it is going back to call `drop` on the `Args`, just guessing...